# Sending PDF as form data / Integromat Webhook

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, make.com

I have a react app, which I'm trying to send a pdf as form data to a webhook on a service called integromat. On integromat, I'm receiving the data as MIME data type. I am able to receive the file, but am receiving it as an IMTBuffer. This is the data I'm given:

"data": "IMTBuffer(61073, binary, 8637a85446e072a21e6e9cdc12f1c9ffb5053674): 255044462d312e350a25bff7a2fe0a322030206f626a0a3c3c202f4c696e656172697a65642031202f4c203631303733202f48205b2037353720313333205d202f4f2036202f45203630373938202f4e2031202f54203630373937203e3e0a656e646f62"

Any ideas as to how to decode this or a better way to send this? Is binary the right way to go? I'm honestly lost at this point on how to handle this or a better way to send the file, as I don't see any more options or documentation on integromat.

Thank You